# Enviar app para aprovação - Facebook Messenger Platform

Tags: facebook

Olá

Estou tentando enviar um app do facebook para aprovação, mas não estou obtendo sucesso. Na aba "Detalhes do aplicativo", clico em editar notas e preencho todos os campos, mas mesmo assim o botão "enviar" fica esmaecido...

Alguém já mexeu com aplicativos para Facebook? Estou esquecendo de algo?

Grato

Comment: Tem uma experiência pequena com apps no Facebook, mas não conheço este processo de "enviar para aprovação". Poderia clarificar do que está falando? Não vejo isto nem a opção enviar em lugar algum.